# Why the night sky is dark?

Tags: universe

I have thought a lot on this point but now needs help. If Universe is Infinite, Then we must be receiving Infinite energy from infinite stars and systems. So what's going on?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking, but I think your asking about [Olber's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox). If so see the article I've linked or [see this search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=olber*) for related articles on this site.

Comment: The universe that we see is not infinite in time and the lights have only been on for about 13 billion years. The universe is actually already dimming. The sky must have been much brighter some time ago. Thanks to the accelerating expansion, the amount of stuff we can actually see and get to is rapidly decreasing and billions of years down the road there won't be much else to see than the galaxy left over by the Milky Way/Andromeda merger plus a few smaller locals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the sky dark at night?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137221/)

Answer (score 0):

Well thought but it is not new, it was thought earlier it is known as [Olbers' paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox). There are several explanations for the dark night sky. I have listened to one such explanation (in some lecture, it is not listed in the Wikipedia link), it says that even if the universe is infinite, the time taken by the light from infinity long distance is infinity and hence we see the finite universe and that is why the night sky is dark. Also the farther portions are moving with more relative speed hence the emission from very far stars may go into invisible spectrum.

Frankly I am not fully convinced with any of these explanations but just try to believe them.

I hope this will help